# How to open a private Safari window from terminal?

Tags: bash, safari, terminal

In order to open a link (for example Google) through Safari on my terminal, I write:

```
open -a safari https://google.com
```

If I want to open this link on a private window instead of a standard one, is there a way or flag that enables it from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

This method would require the user to enable Accessibility mode for System Events, it would show them a dialogue.

You can use AppleScript in Terminal to do what you want:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Safari"
click menu item "New Private Window" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
end tell
end tell'
```